# compactness or not of a Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, compactness

> 1. Is the Lie group generated by this Lie algebra compact or not?

$$
[X_i,X_j]=0, [H_i,H_j]=f^{ijk} X_k, [X_i,H_j]=0 
$$

$f^{123}>0$, and $i,j,k \in \{ 1,2,3\}$. There are 6 generators in total for the Lie algebra.

2. What is the easy way to check the compactness of this Lie group? Is the Lie group unique or not? If there is a unique simply connected Lie group associated to a (finite-dimensional) Lie algebra, then whether the compactness of this simply connected Lie group unique determined?

Any constructive comment or answer will be helpful.

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but there are more than one Lie group for each Lie algebra, so I don't think the question is well defined.  A Lie algebra is called compact if the killing form is negative semidefinite, and a compact Lie algebra always has a Lie group which is compact, but that doesn't mean all of it's Lie groups are compact.

Comment: You might want to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Lie_algebra

Comment: This Killing form is degenerate, but you can define and find a another symmetric bilinear form to replace the Killing form.

Comment: A degenerate form can still be negative semidefinite though.

Comment: As Seth says, there isn't a unique Lie group associated to a Lie algebra. What is true is that there is a unique simply connected Lie group associated to a (finite-dimensional) Lie algebra. Is that the Lie group you're asking about? (For example, $SU(2)$ is the simply connected Lie group associated to its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, but $U(1)$ is not the simply connected Lie group associated to its Lie algebra $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan and @  Seth: It is super informative to learn that there is a unique simply connected Lie group associated to a (finite-dimensional) Lie algebra. How could I find that the unique simply connected Lie group for the given above Lie algebra? I thought this Lie group can be non-compact? But can it be a compact Lie group?

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan and @ Seth: Any more constructive comment or answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the invariant bilinear matrix replacing the degenerate Killing form for this Lie algebra case is:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0& 0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0& 0 & 0 &  1& 0\\
0 & 0& 0 & 0 &  0& 1\\
1 & 0& 0 & 0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 1& 0 & 0 &  0& 0\\
0 & 0& 1 & 0 &  0& 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6 components correspond to $X1,X2,X3,H1,H2,H3$ respectively.

So the invariant bilinear matrix is not positive definite, its eigenvalues are 1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,; so the corresponding Lie group will be non-compact.

Comment: Thanks Idear. Can someone else comment about this answer?